Capacitor discharge through super conductor
Terminals of a charged capacitor,

When connected by a conductor wire

When connected by a superconductor


What happens to destructive energy?
I'm A / L physics teacher and this was a question asked by a student.
Is there any energy losses by Electo Magnetic form?

Inductance is unavoidable, so the equivalent circuit is an RLC series circuit, more or less.
If a completely superconducting system is used, with a vacuum capacitor (no dielectric loss), there is still some loss component, whether due to internal losses, or radiation resistance (coupling from the resonator to the outside world).
Superconducting AC resistance is apparently not well understood.  It is higher for type 2 superconductors (as must be the case: consider a lump of YBCO, it's optically gray or black, but has zero DC resistance below Tc;  somewhere between DC and ~600THz, the resistance goes up!), but even type 1 superconductors have nonzero losses.  A typical application might be a spun niobium resonator, cooled to 2.2 K, operating at 1GHz or so, used to accelerate charged particles in a linear accelerator: the Q factor can be very high indeed, but is still "only" a few hundred million or so -- decidedly not infinite.  This gives a ringdown time constant of a fair fraction of a second, which is not bad at all, considering.
If a superconductor shorts a commercial capacitor of conventional dielectrics and non-superconducting material, those materials contribute loss and the ringdown will be much shorter, perhaps hundreds of microseconds or less.  Or resistance may dominate and it doesn't ring at all, but follows an exponential curve.  Or more generally: it's always an exponential curve, but allowing for complex-valued arguments so that the response moves continuously from oscillatory to damped, as the RLC parameters are varied.

If everything is superconducting then there is no DC resistance in the circuit .The peak current is limited by circuit inductance which is still present.The expected LC sinewave oscillation wont last forever because there will be some Radiation resistance .This means that the wave will die down in the expected exponential fashion. The energy from the charged cap is radiated into space .

A perfect capacitor connected to a perfect inductor forms an LC tank circuit. It resonates with a sine wave at a certain frequency. The frequency is determined by the amount of capacitance and inductance.
